# is it possible to take the number of visualization of instagram image?

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

Is it possible to get a count of how many times an Instagram image has been viewed?

Comment: Are you asking if you can get a count of how many times an Instagram image has been viewed?

Comment: yes, beacuse the api default get me the comment but not the reach and impression...